# Undeclared Identifier error Unity IOS to Xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I've a Unity 5.3.1 iOS project that also uses the new multiplayer network, UNet. Scary stuff. When I build and run the project, I get the following error in Xcode:

```
Use of undeclared identifier `IL2CPP_RAISE_MANAGED_EXCEPTION`
```

The project runs fine in the Unity Editor. It's in a huge Bulk_Generics_10.cpp
script that deals with `System.Comparison1<UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem.PeerInfoPlayer`

Here is the block of code that the error is found.

```
 // System.Void
 System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateDistinctIterator>c__Iterator3`1<System.Object>::Reset()
 extern TypeInfo*
 NotSupportedException_t1382227673_0_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var; extern const
 uint32_t
 U3CCreateDistinctIteratorU3Ec__Iterator3_1_Reset_m_1278777949_0_MetadataUsageId;
 extern "C"  void
 U3CCreateDistinctIteratorU3Ec__Iterator3_1_Reset_m_1278777949_0_gshared
 (U3CCreateDistinctIteratorU3Ec__Iterator3_1_t1454147488_0 * __this,
 const MethodInfo* method) {    static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;   if
 (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)    {       il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method
 (U3CCreateDistinctIteratorU3Ec__Iterator3_1_Reset_m_1278777949_0_MetadataUsageId);
        s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;    }   {
        NotSupportedException_t1382227673_0 * L_0 =
 (NotSupportedException_t1382227673_0 *)il2cpp_codegen_object_new
 (NotSupportedException_t1382227673_0_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var);
        NotSupportedException__ctor_m149930845_0(L_0, /*hidden
 argument*/NULL);       IL2CPP_RAISE_MANAGED_EXCEPTION(L_0);    } }
```

Looks like Unity did not hand it off cleanly to Xcode. I'm wondering if there's some adjustment I need to make in Unity.

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Started facing this issue after moving to Unity 5.3.1p3.

Comment: I downloaded patches from the Unity Web page and the problem went away. Find the patch that matches the Unity version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new problem with the build packages for different platforms being optional in the installer. If you install a platform and then upgrade your version of Unity but don't install that platform on the second install the old version of the platform will remain and cause problems.

My solution was to totally wipe out my Unity3d folder and reinstall with the correct platforms.

related thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp_raise_managed_exception-undeclared-identifier.382377/

Comment: Thanks Meursault334!  I re-installed the latest version and applied patches from Unity page.  One or both worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `System.Linq` is supported by iOS.

Here is a thread also exists regarding this,

Most of Linq extension methods from Linq for Collections are not working with IEnumerables on iOS since they require AOT runtime compiler which is not supported.

However there is a [Linq for iOS](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18131) library on Asset Store that is similar to Linq but doesn't require a runtime compiler. So you can use it on iOS.

Source: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/linq-on-ios.84147/

Comment: Thanks Hamza Hasan! I wasn't customizing or trying to use a Linq Library but if the errors return as mysteriously as they appeared I'll use this tip!